# Proving $\frac{1}{n}<\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)<1$

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for the proof of the following:
$$\frac{1}{n}<\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)<1$$

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to interpret $\ln (n)$ as the area under the curve $y=\frac1x$, chop this area into unit-width sections, and to compare the area of each section with an approximating rectangle. First observe that

$$\ln (n) = \int_1^n \frac{dx}x=\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^k \frac{dx}x.\tag1$$

Next, establish the inequality
$$
\frac1{k-1}>\int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}x>\frac 1k\tag2
$$
for every $k\ge2$. (This is easiest to see from a picture of the graph of $y=\frac1x$.) Rearrange (2) into the form:
$$
0<\frac1{k-1}-\int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}x<\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k.\tag3
$$
Sum (3) from $k=2$ to $n$ and use (1) to obtain:
$$
0<\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k-1}-\ln (n)<1-\frac1n
$$
from which the result follows.